# How do I pass template values when doing a redirect?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, session, redirect

I use the blobstoreuploadhandler and hence must return a self.redirect but I need to pass values to my template. How can I do it? If I can't use template values then I suppose I can use session variables and I've included the beaker session library but I can't understand how to access the session variables in django template. Any idea how I should do it?

I use default builtin django with google app engine and I can access session variables with a request handler but I don't understand how to do it in templates:

```
class Sessiontest(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # Get the session object from the environ
        self.session = self.request.environ['beaker.session']

        # Check to see if a value is in the session
        if 'counter' in self.session:
            counter = self.session['counter'] + 1
            self.session['counter'] = counter

        else:
            self.session['counter'] = 1
            counter = 1
        self.session.save()
        self.response.out.write('counter: %d' % counter)
```

Thanks

Update/edit: My problem is almost exactly like this [Accessing session variable in Django template with Google App Engine (Webapp) - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887664/accessing-session-variable-in-django-template-with-google-app-engine-webapp-p) but with the library beaker instead of gaeutilities

Update: Here's some of the code. we see that using HTTP GET to pass the values won't be very good since there's an anti-spam test that should hide the values:

```
def post(self, view):
    message = ''
    challenge = self.request.get('recaptcha_challenge_field').encode('utf-8')
    response  = self.request.get('recaptcha_response_field').encode('utf-8')
    remoteip  = os.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
    cResponse = captcha.submit(
                 challenge,
                 response,
                 CAPTCHA_PRV_KEY,
                 remoteip)
    if cResponse.is_valid:
        isHuman=True
    else:#failed anti-spam test and can try again
        isHuman=False
        #Reprint the form
        import util
        template_values = {'isHuman':isHuman,'user' : users.get_current_user(),}
        template_values.update(dict(current_user=self.current_user, facebook_app_id=FACEBOOK_APP_ID))
        template_values.update(dict(capture=captcha.displayhtml(public_key = CAPTCHA_PUB_KEY, use_ssl = False, error = None)))
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'market', 'market_insert.html')
        self.redirect("/ai") # Here the values aren't passed on and I must make a redirect
```

Comment: I'm confused by your reference to Beaker. Are you using Django on GAE, or just the Django templates on top of something like webapp?

Comment: Can you post the actual code related to your problem?  Forget the beaker stuff - show the file upload code, tell use what URL it redirects to, and what URL you want it to redirect to.  Accessing beaker sessions in a template should be a separate question.

Comment: Code posted. Passing values via HTTP GET is not a good idea since I pass HTML and also values that should be hidden

Comment: Please, please don't pass values in a session. This completely destroys the HTTP model, and means that things like browsing in multiple tabs will break. If you must send data you can't embed in a query string, store it in the datastore and send the entity's key in the query string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are doing a redirect you might have to redirect with the variables that you wish to keep in the GET string. So you redirect from

```
/myview/
```

to

```
/myview2/?variable1=value
```

However, I think you should really look to see why you are doing redirects. I tend to do them after a POST to a form, and if the user needs to be logged on, I redirect to a login screen with

```
/authentication/login/?next=/view/they/wanted/to/see
```

Otherwise you could keep things in cookies but its not the best way to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

How about letting your class inherit from multiple classes, both requesthandler class and blobstoreuploadhandler, in that way you can both render your template with values with the functions in the requesthandler, and use the functions in blobstoreuploadhandler?

A class definition with multiple base classes looks as follows:

```
class DerivedClassName(Base1, Base2, Base3):
    <statement-1>
    ...
    <statement-N>
```